# ModelState.IsValid keeps being false because of SelectList in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a strange problem: a model that has a `SelectList`, but in `POST` action, `ModelState.IsValid` is false because of that `SelectList`:

```cs
public class CarMakesViewModel 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList Nationalities { get; set; }

    public Guid NationalityId { get; set; }
}
```

In Edit view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="NationalityId" class="form-label required"></label>
    <select asp-for="NationalityId" name="NationalityId" asp-items="Model.Nationalities" class="form-control "></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="NationalityId" class="text-danger form-control-sm"></span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(CarMakesViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Edit Code
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    await GetSelectList(model);

    return View(model);
}
```

In the `post`, the `Nationality` `SelectList` is null and that is the usual but why `Model.State.IsValid` is always equal to `false`?

The error says:

> Nationalities is required

And to be noted select option is rendered with text and values normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to apply [`[ValidateNever]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute to remove validate of the `Nationalities` on the server side?

When applied to a property, the validation system excludes that property.

```cs
public class CarMakesViewModel 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ValidateNever]
    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList Nationalities { get; set; }

    public Guid NationalityId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably using net 6. You can just make list nullable

```
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList? Nationalities { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to initalize your select list in the view modol.  You can do it in the constructor or use a property initializer:

```
public List<SelectListItem> EnvironmentSelectList { get; set; } = new();
```